# How to add inner text of link in Web Crawler?

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler

In web crawler ,I want to write hyperlink inner text along with url.How can I achieve that?

ex-

```html
<a href="www.example.com">Example</a>
```

for this link I want to write in crawled file as

"Example  www.example.com"

I have tried LinkFinder in python,here I am able to get link but not able to get inner text.

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from link_finder import LinkFinder

def gather_links(page_url):
        html_string = ''
        try:
            response = urlopen(page_url)
            if 'text/html' in response.getheader('Content-Type'):
                html_bytes = response.read()
                html_string = html_bytes.decode("utf-8")
            finder = LinkFinder('',page_url)
            finder.feed(html_string)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            
        return finder.page_links()
```

Comment: Can you provide a few examples of what the `finder.page_links()` output looks like?

Comment: finder.page_links() get exact link [href attribute value of tag a] like 
 www.example.com

Comment: Your question is still not clear: if your link is `<a href="www.example.com">Text</a>`, is your desired output `Example www.example.com` or `Text www.example.com`?

Comment: I would like to get output 'Text www.example.com'

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking to get not just the link but also the text inside the link, you will need to use an HTML parser library. One of these two should work for you:

```
link = '<a href="www.example.com">Text</a>'

import lxml.html

target = lxml.html.fromstring(link)
```

or

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs(link,'lxml')
target = soup.find('a')
```

And then, using either library:

```
my_str = target.text+' '+target.get('href')
my_str
```

Output:

> 'Text www.example.com'